Invoking custom newThread func in ThreadFactory when using ExecutorService
I am attempting to use a custom ThreadFactory implementation that allows me to use a custom object instead of a generic Runnable object.
Below is as minimal of an example as I could produce. The Foo() class definition and Main() are largely irrelevant, beyond creating a functional scaffold for my question. I am using an ExecutorService's execute() method to invoke my ExampleFactory. This question largely pertains the proper utilization of an overloaded ThreadFactory when invoked via an ExecutorService. Context after the code.
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory

class ExampleFactory implements ThreadFactory{
    public Thread newThread(Foo f){
        String threadName = "ID: " + f.getID();
        return new Thread(f, threadName);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r){
        if (! (r instanceof Foo)) {
            throw new IllegalArugmentException("Not Foo");
        }
        
        return new Thread(r, "Boo"); //won't get here, thrown exception
    }
}
...
import java.lang.Runnable;


public class Foo implements Runnable{
    
    public int ID = 0; 
    
    public Foo(int i){
        this.ID = i;
    }
    
    public int getID(){
        return this.ID;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running (Runnable): " + this.ID);
    }
}
...
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new ExampleFactory());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            Foo f = new Foo( i );
            System.out.println("Executing i: "+ i);
            e.execute(f);   
      }
    }
}

When using an ExecutorService, I do not see newThread(Foo f) getting called, but instead, newThread(Runnable r).
Is there a better way to do this?
I want to be able to call getter methods from Foo in the Thread Factory for labeling and other purposes pre-.start().
This seems to be occurring because ExecutorService's execute() method expects a Runnable object, and by calling .execute(), I am casting Foo -> Runnable. Given that I was using a ThreadFactory, I had expected that the ExampleFactory would be invoked first, and then execute() would take the returned object.
I could overload the Executor Service's execute(Runnable) method to have a similar execute(Foo f), but that seems like overkill for this issue? Particularly due to the fact that I would merely be changing the input and return types, but otherwise preserving previous functionality?

If you place a debug breakpoint in ExampleFactory.newThread you'll see that the ThreadPoolExecutor is wrapping the the Foo instance in an internal private Worker object (that itself implements Runnable).  The source code says why this is done:

Class Worker mainly maintains interrupt control state for threads running tasks, along with other minor bookkeeping. This class opportunistically extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer to simplify acquiring and releasing a lock surrounding each task execution. This protects against interrupts that are intended to wake up a worker thread waiting for a task from instead interrupting a task being run. We implement a simple non-reentrant mutual exclusion lock rather than use ReentrantLock because we do not want worker tasks to be able to reacquire the lock when they invoke pool control methods like setCorePoolSize. Additionally, to suppress interrupts until the thread actually starts running tasks, we initialize lock state to a negative value, and clear it upon start (in runWorker).

That Worker object is closed for access, so you cannot get at the underling delegate.
Step back a moment:
I think you are mixing up the lifecycle of the Runnable and Thread.  In a long-running JVM, you'll have a small number of Threads which are often long-lived and service many instances of Runnable/Callable in typical applications (perhaps not yours).  Therefore naming your Thread somehow named after the first Foo it handles doesn't seem right.  (Thread creation/destruction is expensive, this is why JVMs keep pools of them waiting for work.)
Assuming what you want to do is label the thread to indicate to an observer what it is doing based on the current work; if this is only what you want to do (and I see you said "labeling and other purposes") you can more simply call Thread.setName(..) once you are running the thread.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("ID: " + this.getID());
        System.out.println("Running (Runnable): " + this.ID);
    }

I have tried this before, and monitoring tools don't expect the Thread's name to keep changing, so you may not achieve what you want by this means.
You said "and other purposes".  Well, maybe you should look in a different direction... Look at subclassing ThreadPoolExecutor and implement beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) as this might offer what you want:

Method invoked prior to executing the given Runnable in the given thread. This method is invoked by thread t that will execute task r, and may be used to re-initialize ThreadLocals, or to perform logging.


I have some concerns wrt naming the Thread from within the thread itself, as opposed to the Thread that owns/manages it, but this is definitely the simplest solution, as I do not need to reimplement a severalty of classes to accomplish the same things.

The accepted answer to your question by AndrewL is indeed accurate. If you print the canonicalName of the passed-in Runnable, the type is java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker.
Subclassing ThreadPoolExecutor gives access to the underlying Runnable instance. The following code prints the canonicalName of the delegated Runnable i.e, SimpleThread
public MyThreadPoolExecutor() {     
             
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue) ;   
}

@Override
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    
    System.out.println(r.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    
    SimpleThread simpleThread = null;
    
    if(r instanceof SimpleThread)
        simpleThread = (SimpleThread) r;
    
    //Instance methods are now accessible
    
}

//Driver

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ExecutorService svc = new MyThreadPoolExecutor() ;
    
    svc.execute(new SimpleThread());        

}

